# Searching Listview with onClick view showing wrong results

Tags: android, listview

Can anyone help me how to fix wrong result from searchview of listview. for example I have data from list view (1,2,3,4,5) When I search data 2 from searchview an I click it, always data 1 that show it, and when I didn't search data from searchview the result if true, I click data 1 show 1, 2 show 2

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final String[] values= new String[]{"button1","button2","buttton3"};
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item,android.R.id.text1,values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if(position==0){
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent,0);
            }
            if(position==1){
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main3Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent,1);
            }
            if(position==2){
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent,2);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter for the `startActivityForResult` is a code that is intended to identify result sent to the initiating activity. The ideal way to pass a vale to another activity is via Intent extras (i.e. extra information to be sent as part of the Intent). So rather than `startActivityForResult(intent,value_to_be_used)` you should use something along the lines of:-

```
    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("MYKEYFORTHEVALUE",position)
    startActivityForResult(myintent,111);
```

This would work for all three.

In the `Main2Activity` you'd have something like the following to retrieve the value :-

```
int myvaluefromtheotheractivity = getIntent.getIntExtra("MYKEYFORTHEVALUE",-1);
if (mymyvaluefromtheotheractivity < 0) {
    // handle value not being obtained for some reason
}
```

- **MYKEYFORTHEVALUE** being a string used to identify the specific value as you can add more than 1 value.
- The 2nd parameter (depending upon the type) is the default value, so -1 should not be a position so allows you to detect nothing being sent in the extra.

Comment: THANKS! i will try to implement it